# How Can I Show the users task day wise in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with users details with date and task hours.
I need to show the total hours spent by users weekly

```
Name   date        Hours
----- ------      -------
Ram   2018-11-01    1.5
Ram   2018-11-02      2
Shyam 2018-11-01     3
Shyam  2018-11-02    5
```

I need a my sql query which will display the total hours spent by each users in all days entered in the table.

I want output like

```
Name  2018-11-01   2018-11-02   Total Hour
----  -----------  ----------   ----------
Ram   1.5           2           3.5
Shyam  3            5            8
```

I am new to mysql. 
Can anyone help me with writing the query for this?

Thanks

Comment: You should not use a database to format your data pretty. That should be done in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could help you, if you're looking something like that :

```
SELECT first_name, date, SUM(hour) AS Total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY first_name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36270b8

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I need the dates as column which I mentioned

Comment: This might help you : https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot